# World of Warcraft Official Armory Updates

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I was wondering how often and when the data on the Armory gets updated? Does it only update once you log out or a certain time of day?

Also, could this tool be used to view other people's characters (to see the gear, gems and talents)?

Thanks in advance*

Comment: Last time I looked (and that was ages ago) you could watch any character's gear if you knew that character's name and the realm it's saved on. But by the time the Armory went online, I had already stopped playing WoW and I was looking at a private server's Armory, so maybe it's not an official feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Armory of a character is updated upon logging out of said character. This works for gear and talent choices but I am not 100% sure if very recently acquired achievements will show up straight away.

As far as I am aware, all characters over a certain level (10?) appear on the Armory. I also believe that there is no way of making a character 'private'. A user could remove all the gear and talents of a character to hide what they are doing if they so desired.

The majority of character data is public, but some can only be viewed if you log into battle.net of the account which owns the character. The calendar is example of private data.

There are quite a few ways to search for characters on the Armory. By character name, realm, guild and even arena team I think. Other advanced filters exist as well, but I am not very familiar with them.

Hope this helps.

Edit: As Ramhound has pointed out in the comments, upon logging out the armory is not always updated instantaneously. It depends on several behind the scenes factors (i.e. server load, maintenance). The updates are queued however and should eventually happen. Thanks Ramhound.

Comment: The armory is suppose to update when you log into the character, it does not always update, it all depends on several behind the scenes factors ( i.e. server load ).  The updates are queued though.

Comment: Verification functionality on some third party sites which use the armory api makes me believe it is the other way round (logout). A few of them ask the user to remove a piece or pieces of gear and then logout so they can verify you have control of that character. Thanks for the information about the queue, this is definitely the case and your request can be delayed.

Comment: I Aplogize I actually did mean logout.  My actual point is that its not guaranteed to happen, and various situations, can delay it (i.e. service maintentance).

Comment: Edited my answer to include your useful information.

Comment: The Mobile Armory seems to lag behind the website information as well (at least on the iPhone).  It has even been a couple of days before I saw guild and achievement information updated; more than likely for the same reasons as stated in the answer.